# Date getting changed after parquet to csv conversion

Tags: scala, csv, date, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am facing one issue, while loading data from s3. In the conversionnfron parquet to csv, a default date is changing, from 0001-01-03 to 001-01-01.
The source dra value getting changed.

In the spark config, we did below 2 addition but no help:

```
Spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite CORRECTED
Spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead LEGACY
```

CAN anyone else have idea??

Comment: Where exactly is the date ```0001-01-03``` and where ```001-01-01```?

Comment: In source s3 -parquet data date is like 0001-01-03. From there we are using spark job to extract data and creating the parquet to csv file.  Then date becomes 0001-01-01. It is converted. Only for this date there is issue. Other dates are fine.     This is a default date from source. Spark version is 3.0.1

Comment: I come across this question when I am researching why 0001-01-01 from source data was converted to 0001-01-03 in Spark. Your issue is the other way around. Looks like 0001-01-01 and 0001-01-03 are somehow equal. Did you find the answer?